# Are there ways to catch and detect leaks from a clothes washer? Some kind of tray?

Tags: leak

If a clothes washing machine begins leaking, are there ways to catch and detect the leak as there are with hot water heaters?

If so, by what terms can I search to find such parts?

Answer (score 3):

There are trays available in the big box home stores for this. Some come with a knock out for a drain hose if you have a place to drain excess water to. They are sized so most washing machines will fit. The last I bought, in 2017 were about $30 each.

Comment: Such a tray also useful for under the kitty litterbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think the terms are:  water leak detector:

1. Honeywell Home Water Leak Detector
2. Wasserstein WiFi Water Leak Sensor
3. Roost Smart Water Leak and Freeze Detector
4. Insteon Water Leak Sensor
5. Samsung SmartThings Water Leak Sensor
6. LeakSMART Sensor
7. Govee WiFi Water Leak Detector
8. Fibaro Flood Sensor (HomeKit)
9. Zircon Leak Alert WiFi
10. iHome Battery Powered WiFi Dual Leak Sensor

Answer (score 1):

Put in a waterproof floor with a floor drain.

Comment: Or if you know that it leaks and want to know where, slide a sheet of newspaper under it and look occasionally.